# Looking for a simple rich-text editor usable from VBA

Tags: vba, richtext

I'd like to allow my users to enter rich text (with bold, italic & underline, but probably nothing more than that) in an entry box on a VBA userform.

I don't want the user to have to install anything, so I need this to be something that leverages what Office or Windows already provide. The obvious candidate is the Windows built-in [Rich Edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I did a quick test and verified that I could create a window of this type from VBA, but what it then lacks is all the UI, etc. I could really use a leg-up as to how I then turn this into something usable.

I'm happy to consider alternative controls, so long as they're guaranteed to require no installation (other than as part of the Excel file containing the rest of my VBA code). It needs to work on Windows XP and up, and Office 2003 and up.

Answer (score 1):

You could just try making a simple UI yourself.  Add a command button to the form that will bold the selected text in the rich edit control.  Or add a command button that will italicize or copy or paste.  Your imagination is your limit.

I was checking Rich Edit Version 1.0 in Excel 2010, and I could access the text in the control.

Comment: What control do you drop onto the form? I don't see a "rich edit" in my toolbox, even when I choose "additional controls".

Comment: You'll need to set a reference to the control from VBA.  Press Alt + F11, click on Tools > References.  In my computer it is called "msrtedit 1.0 Type Library".  Or, in 2010, click on Developer > Insert > More Controls (under ActiveX Controls) > MSREdit Class.

Comment: I don't see that on my machine. I assume this is essentially the same problem as with Dennis Palmer's answer - the DLL is only present if you have particular software installed. Maybe Access again (I wonder if this is in fact the same control).

Comment: Based on your question, I thought you already had access to the builtin RichEdit control (which is MSREdit) and you just wanted to find out how to enable a UI for it.  I couldn't find any reference to enable a UI for the control, so I suggest building your own.  Could you please clarify what I am thinking?  Thank you.

Comment: I have the riched20.dll file on my machine, and if I do a LoadLibrary on that, I can then create a window of type RichEdit20W using the Win32 CreateWindowEx function. But, there's nothing in Tools->References or in Additional Controls that corresponds to the names you mention. Browsing to the riched20.dll DLL from Tools->References gives me access to a library named "tom" with a host of useful-looking objects, but none of these appear to be creatable from VBA, so that doesn't really help. I'm very interested in your solution - it's just that it doesn't seem to be available to me...

Comment: Okay, I just installed Office 2003 Small Business Edition on a cleanly formatted computer with Windows XP SP3 and discovered that the rich edit control is not on that computer.  Sorry!  I don't think you're going to be able to get a good answer without spending some money, either on a new version of Office or just purchasing a 3rd party rich edit control.  Saying all that, this website may also be of some help to you for your specific request:  http://www.lebans.com/richtext.htm

Comment: thanks for trying. Since I'm looking for something that I can distribute to users around the world - who may have any version of Office and Windows - buying something or changing *my* configuration doesn't really help. But, at least I'm now reasonably confident that it just can't be done.

Comment: If you do buy a 3rd party rich edit control, they usually provide a license that allows you to distribute it with your application.  Also, did you check Lebans' website?  There is a link to a way of doing it in Access without an ActiveX control.  It's at the bottom of the page...

Comment: Thanks. I set out to find something that did not need any installation, so was hoping to leverage what comes with Excel/Windows. Anything related to Access is ruled out for similar reasons.

Comment: If you take a look at the Access forms that Lebans made, you can adapt that to your Excel forms.  He is simply using the common dialog library built into Windows with API calls to make his own custom RTF control.  I suggest taking a peek at it before dismissing it so quickly.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the Lebans stuff working up to a point, though the code there is pretty hideous. Now my problem is that of getting the styled text back into an Excel cell... (Excel doesn't understand RTF, and so far the only way I've found to resolve this is to copy the RTF from the control into Word, then copy it from Word back into Excel! Yuk.)

Comment: We might want to consider just using HTML instead of RTF.  I found an interesting article about using HTML in cells [here.](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/02/23/html-in-cells-ii/)  Review the comments in that article for some VBA ideas in implementing the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone searching for this still. As Gary McGill stated, "Microsoft InkEdit Control" is your best option.

Use the link below for a reference on the variables it can use:

https://www.thevbprogrammer.com/Ch10/10-06-RichTextBox.htm

Comment: To note:  The link instructs you to access InkEdit via the Components menu.  This is only accessible via VB6.  If you are using VBA (through an MS Office application), you obviously, then you will need to set a reference to this control via Tools --> References --> Select Microsoft InkEdit Control v1.0

Answer (score 0):

With the Toolbox window open in Excel's Visual Basic editor, select Tools->Additional Controls from the menu. Check the box next to `MSREdit Class`. This will add the rich text control to your toolbox. From there you can add it to a UserForm.

I tested this control in both Office 2003 on Windows XP and Office 2010 on Windows 7. It looks like you'll still need to provide the UI for allowing the user to toggle bold, italics and underline.

It does accept a paste (via `Ctrl+V`) of some rich text that I copied from Word, but I couldn't figure out how to make it switch font formating while typing text into the control.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I don't see "MSREdit Class" in the list. Perhaps it gets installed with something else (in which case, it's not the guaranteed-to-work-without-installation solution I'm looking for).

Comment: I couldn't tell if it was the same as the Rich TextBox Control 6.0. It's in `MSRTEDIT.DLL` which was under `C:\Program Files\Micorosft Office` on my systems, so I thought it was installed with Office itself.

Comment: I think it may be installed with Access, since many of the Google hits I got when searching for info were related to Access.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here just to rule it out...

It seems that the "Microsoft InkEdit Control", which is available from "Additional Controls" on the toolbox, is a superset of the Rich Text Edit control (as the name suggests, it also supports Ink).

It's hard to tell whether this is widely installed - it is on my XP/2003 machine, but not on my 2K/2K machine. (I've seen it said that it's installed with Vista and Win7, but clearly there are earlier versions too).

Anyway, I'm ruling this out because using the control results in a message at runtime to the effect that the ActiveX control is "unsafe" (presumably related to the well-known issue with the Rich Text Control itself).